# Why are there only sometimes compiler errors when accessing a property without self?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, declared-property

I noticed that in some old versions of Xcode you could use properties of objects without `self` just fine.
Now it gives me an error when I try to access my property without `self`, but today I'm writing this code, and it works fine, and doesn't give me any errors.

```
[aCoder encodeObject:itemName forKey:@"itemName"];
```

Why is it this way? Why don't I get an error in this case? Why is an error raised in other cases? Why can't this behavior be unified, and what should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have never been able to access properties without `self`. If you didn't use `self`, then you were directly accessing the instance variable that had the same name as the property. This has caused endless issues for many developers.

This is why the latest compilers (in the latest versions of Xcode) generate property ivars with a leading underscore. This way, if you forget to use `self` when trying to access the property, you get an error because there is no ivar with the same name.

To unify your experience you should use the following pattern with older compilers:

Define `@property int foo;`. Then define ivar `int _foo`. And then use `@synthesize foo = _foo;`.

With newer compilers you simply declare `@property int foo` and you are done. The compiler will generate the ivar `int _foo` for you.

In both cases you use `self.foo` for the property and `_foo` to directly access the ivar.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a property with **new LLVM compiler**, it creates an ivar named `_property` .

If you don't over-ride the auto-`synthesize`d then you need to use `_property` or `self.property`.

In your case it looks like you are using old compiler (i.e. coming with XCode4.3 bacwards) or you have over-riden auto-synthesized as:

```
@synthesize aCoder;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean this warning:

[image]

A lot of projects do not enable many warnings in their build settings, so that could be one reason that you aren't seeing this warning.

There are also certain methods where it is common to access instance variables directly, and Xcode will ignore direct ivar access; these include `init*` and `dealloc` methods (but unfortunately not getter/setter methods).

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. You can directly access ivars or access properties in any method. Xcode doesn't care either way (and neither does the compiler).

Comment: The compiler does care, it's just that most people don't enable many warnings. If you like to use things like `-Wall` and the new `-Weverything` you get warnings like this: http://i.imgur.com/II4vGFw.png?1?3012

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen that before. Are you saying that with this enabled, the warning appears everywhere except `init*` and `dealloc`?

Comment: Yes. The only annoying thing is that overriding setters and getters and directly accessing the instance variable (as you would) still triggers the warning. You have to add a pragma to avoid that for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you define properties in a class and `@synthesize` them to use the same naming, then you can access them without self

e.g.

In .h

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *str1;
```

In .m

```
@synthesize str1 = str1;

str1 = @"hello";
self.str1 = @"hello"; // Or this
```

If you don't use explicit `@synthesize`, then XCode automatically does `@synthesize property = _property` (since recently) so you can do the following

In .h

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *str1;
```

In .m

```
_str1 = @"hello";
self._str1 = @"hello"; // Or this
```

You won't be able to use `self` if the property is defined in a parent class. You'll have to synthesize in your current class to be able to use it.